# Какую лицензию можно использовать для использовании чужой работы?

Tags: лицензирование

Собираюсь сделать игровой проект на основе аниме "Наруто" с открытым исходным кодом и без профита.
Возможно ли это сделать без спроса и какая лицензия для этого нужна? Какие лицензии могут быть использованы?

Я видел в некоторых проектах лицензии с фразами "все права пренадлежат правообладателю" и т.д.

Comment: Невозможно. И дело не только в лицензии, но и в торговой марке

Comment: Это зависит не от лицензии вашего проекта, а от лицензии "Наруто". Если лицензия аниме "Наруто" позволяет это делать - то возможно. Если не позволяет - то невозможно.

Comment: @Эникейщик когда у них не указана лицензия, а допустим указано следующее "NARUTO © 1999 by Masashi Kishimoto/SHUEISHA Inc." то это копирайт? Можно ли использовать копилефт?

Comment: Почитайте, что такое копилефт и к чему он относится.